# Need help understanding what is happening in this Array sorting ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I am sorting an Array of reindeer in alphabetic order by last name.  The following code has me confused:

```
def sort_reindeer reindeer_names
  reindeer_names.sort_by { |n| n.split.last }
end
```

I understand everything besides how the split method works when it isn't given an argument to identify where to split?   And then I am not sure what last does..Is it just returning the last element in the array?(I know it can't be since the array comes back sorted)

So I guess the last is doing the sorting somehow?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show a possible sample of `reindeer_names` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-split) says

> If [the argument] is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is
>   the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified.

So it's splitting on whitespace.

As for `last`, it *is* just returning the last element of the Array. `sort_by` uses that value to sort the array.